# How do I pad string representations of integers in Haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, formatting

I'l looking for an idiomatic (perhaps built-in) way of padding string representations of integers with zeros on the left.

In my case the integers are never more than 99 so

```
fix r = if length r == 1 then '0':r else r
fix.show <$> [1..15]
```

works. But I expect there is a better way.

How do I pad string representations of integers in Haskell?

Comment: I would recommend using [`Text.Printf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Text-Printf.html), since it's a built in module for string formatting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`printf` style formatting is availble via the `Text.Printf` module:

```
import Text.Printf

fmt x = printf "%02d" x
```

Or to special case the formatting of 0:

```
fmt 0 = "  "
fmt x = printf "%02d" x
```

Comment: I'd like to use this, but there's a case missing, from my original question. Can I make this show `0` as `"  "` (two spaces), rather than `"00"`?

Comment: Thanks. But nothing clever to do that in `printf` correct?

Answer (score 13):

```
> (\x -> replicate (3 - length x) '0' ++ x) "2"
"002"
> (\x -> replicate (3 - length x) '0' ++ x) "42"
"042"
> (\x -> replicate (3 - length x) '0' ++ x) "142"
"142"
> (\x -> replicate (3 - length x) '0' ++ x) "5142"
"5142"
```

The above exploits the fact that `replicate` returns the empty string on negative argument.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, I add here a program padding *any* list of strings with a character passed as an argument.

Rather than taking the maximum of the lengths from the get go, I use an instance of [circular programming](https://wiki.haskell.org/Circular_programming): if you look carefully, you'll see that `n` is the result of a computation... in which it is used!

```
pad :: Char -> [String] -> [String]
pad c xs = ys where
  (ys, n)         = foldr cons ([],0) xs
  cons x (acc, m) = ((replicate (n - m') c ++ x) : acc, max m m')
    where m' = length x
```

Comment: That's an interesting technique, but I don't think it's of much value in this case. If, on the other hand, you wanted to pad out the *end* of each string, then using a similar technique with lazy natural numbers could add potentially useful laziness.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
pad0 n x = take (n - length sx) (cycle "0") ++ sx 
  where sx = show x

pad0 3 1
=> "001"
pad0 3 11
=> "011"
pad0 3 111
=> "111"

["COMP" ++ pad0 3 x | x <- [1..8] ]  
=> ["COMP001","COMP002","COMP003","COMP004","COMP005","COMP006","COMP007","COMP008"]
```