# Haskell: Convert an Int into a String of length n

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Haskell beginner here.

I have a list of integers [1..n] and would like to turn them into a String where every number takes up 3 spaces. Example:

```
[6..12] becomes
" 6  7  8  9 10 11 12"
```

So a one-digit number is surrounded by 2 blanks whereas a two-digit number only has one blank in front.

Using **unwords** (and **show** for converting the Ints to Strings) obviously only sets one blank between every number.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be achieved?
Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Do you have code that solves any part of this problem?  If so, please post it.

Comment: Can you think of a way to write a function that does the task for just one number? `f :: Int -> String`, `f 100 == "100"`, `f 32 == " 32"`, `f 8 == " ︁ 8"`?

Comment: But this is not a string of length `n`, since there are spaces and some numbers have multiple digits. Can you please show what you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pad string representations of integers in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311461/how-do-i-pad-string-representations-of-integers-in-haskell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your comments. I don’t know why I didn’t think of this before but now I wrote a function like Ry- suggested.

```
spaces i 
  | length (show i) == 1 = “ “ ++ show i ++ “ “
  | length (show i) == 2 = “ “ ++ show i
  | otherwise = show i
```

I then mapped it to every element of the list and concatenated it (n is defined in the function)

```
function :: Int -> String
function n = concat (map spaces [1..n])
```

Comment: `concat (map f xs)` is better done in one step as `concatMap f xs`.