# Haskell Display String into 8 columns

Tags: list, haskell, string-formatting

I have 
type person = (String,  Float,  Float,  [Int])
             ** name, height,  weight,  miles walked past week**

The [Int] will contain data for how many miles the person walked on each day for the past 7 days 
e.g. [5,8,12,7,12,6,9]

My testData consists of multiple peoples data and I want to return all names and the 7 daily figures of the miles they walked as a single string, neatly into separate rows for each person and have the miles walked data lined up in columns.

e.g. testData = [(John, 1.76, 63, [5,8,12,7,12,6,9]), (Hannah, 1.64, 56, [6,9,10,9,5,13,13]), (Lewis, 1.80, 73, [4,6,2,6,8,4,6])]

I want this returned like:

[Return result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JaPt.png)

what is the best way to do this in haskell? Thanks

My Code --

```
personToString :: [Person] -> String   
personToString [] = []   
personToString ((name,height,weight,miles):person)=   
   name ++ take (9 - length name) (cycle " ") ++ intercalate ", " (map show miles) ++ "\n \n" ++ personToString person
```

This returns what I want but the miles digits don't line up as there is a mix of single and double digit figures

Comment: Have you looked at module [Text.Printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html) ?

Comment: Hi, welcome so SO. Please show any attempts you have made so far, and where you are getting stuck. This will help potential answerers answer in a helpful way. Otherwise, this just becomes a "write me code" question, and they are somewhat frowned upon on SO.

Answer (score 1):

OK, somebody took the trouble of putting together module [Text.Printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Printf.html).

Seems just a job cut for it here, so let's give it a try:

```
import  Data.List (intercalate)
import  Text.Printf

type Person = (String, Float, Float, [Int]) -- ** name, height, weight, miles...

testData  :: [Person]
testData = [("John",   1.76, 63, [5,8,12,7,12,6,9]),
            ("Hannah", 1.64, 56, [6,9,10,9,5,13,13]),
            ("Lewis",  1.80, 73, [4,6,2,6,8,4,6])]

showMileList :: [Int] -> String
showMileList mileList = intercalate ","  $
                            map (printf "%3d") mileList

personToString :: Person -> String
personToString (name, h, w, miles) =
    (printf "%-9s" name) ++ " "                    ++
       (printf "%5.2f " h) ++ (printf "%3.0f " w)  ++
       (showMileList miles)

printAsLines :: [String] -> IO ()
printAsLines xs = mapM_ putStrLn  xs  -- a loop in the IO monad


main = do
   let strings = map  personToString  testData
   printAsLines strings
```

### Program output:

```
John       1.76  63   5,  8, 12,  7, 12,  6,  9
Hannah     1.64  56   6,  9, 10,  9,  5, 13, 13
Lewis      1.80  73   4,  6,  2,  6,  8,  4,  6
```

Sole hitch in the deal I could find, the module is a bit hard to use under ghci: any looseness in the typing around `printf` seems to derail the interactive compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is properly padding columns with spaces. Going from [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32313738/7096763), we can define our own left-padding and right-padding functions that take the desired length, the padding character, the string to pad, and return a padded string of the correct length (or more, if the string was already longer than the required length):

```
lPadWithChar, rPadWithChar :: Int -> Char -> String -> String
lPadWithChar l c s = replicate (l - length s) c ++ s
rPadWithChar l c s = s ++ replicate (l - length s) c
```

The name of your `personToList` function is a bit confusing, since it takes a list of `Person`. It would be more readable as `personsToList`. To show our padding functions in action, we can look into formatting a single `Person` without worrying for now about recursion:

```
personToString :: Person -> String
personToString (name, _, _, miles) = rPadWithChar 10 ' ' name
  ++ intercalate "," (map (lPadWithChar 3 ' ' . show) miles)
```

Notice you also don't need to bind the second and third elements of the `Person`, since you're not using them. This is standard practice in Haskell and makes it easier, just by looking at the first few characters of a function, that it only uses the `name` and `miles` elements.

Finally, we deal with the recursion and  multi-line formatting in a separate function which accepts a `[Person]`.

```
personsToString :: [Person] -> String
personsToString = concat . intersperse "\n" . map personToString
                  --You only need one \n, right?
```

Here, I used the higher-order functions `map` and `intersperse` to abstract the recursion away, but you can easily turn this into explicit recursion. Here it is in action:

```
>>> let testData = [("John", 1.76, 63, [5,8,12,7,12,6,9]), ("Hannah", 1.64, 56, [6,9,10,9,5,13,13]), ("Lewis", 1.80, 73, [4,6,2,6,8,4,6])]
>>> putStrLn $ personsToString testData
John        5,  8, 12,  7, 12,  6,  9
Hannah      6,  9, 10,  9,  5, 13, 13
Lewis       4,  6,  2,  6,  8,  4,  6
```

From the formatting of your test data, I assume that this is from a course. Just note that using tuples to carry around complex groups of real-world information is very error-prone and makes for hard-to-maintain code. For example, consider what would happen if you had a requirement to make the miles the first element of the tuple, you would end up with a completely broken API. The standard way to fix this is by using [record syntax](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses).